# How do you iterate through objects in a blob on google cloud storage? Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to figure out how to iterate over objects in a blob in google cloud storage. The address is similar to this:

```
gs://project_ID/bucket_name/DIRECTORY/file1 
gs://project_ID/bucket_name/DIRECTORY/file2
gs://project_ID/bucket_name/DIRECTORY/file3
gs://project_ID/bucket_name/DIRECTORY/file4
...
```

The DIRECTORY on the GCS bucket has a bunch of different files that I need to iterate over, so that I can check when it was last updated (to see if it is a new file there) so that I can pull the contents.

Example function

```
def getNewFiles():
    storage_client = storage.Client(project='project_ID')
    try:
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
    except:
        storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)

    for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix='DIRECTORY'):
        if blob.name == 'DIRECTORY/':
            **Iterate through this Directory**
            **CODE NEEDED HERE***
            **Figure out how to iterate through all files here**
```

I have gone through the python api and the client library, and can't find any examples of this working..

Answer (score 2):

[According to Google Cloud Client Library for Python docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob), `blob.name`:

> This corresponds to the unique path of the object in the bucket

Therefore `blob.name` will return something like this:

```
DIRECTORY/file1
```

If you are already including the parameter `prefix='DIRECTORY'` when using the `list_blobs()` [method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html?highlight=list_blob#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.list_blobs) you can get all your files in your directory by doing:

```
for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix='DIRECTORY'):
    print(blob.name)
```

You can use something like `blob.name.lstrip('DIRECTORY')` or [the standard library re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to clean the string and get only the file name.

However, according to what you said: "so that I can check when it was last updated (to see if it is a new file there)" if you are looking for some function to be triggered when you have new files in your bucket, you can use [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/). You have [the docs here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) on how to use them with Cloud Storage when new objects are created. Although as of current date (Feb/2018) you can only write Cloud Functions using NODE.JS